# PhoneGap InAppBrowser window.open multiple times

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

We open our home page on onDeviceReady function in index.html and when an item is scanned, a different url is opened. We have problem in opening multiple/different URL using windows.open. It has LoadError on opened website and it breaks some functionality. If we close the ref.close(); for first windows.open, we do not see the LoadError and opened site perform well but we cannot open new URL or redirect to another page on scan event. 
Here is the code which is causing problem. In logs we see this error.

DVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1
[22979:c07] webView:didFailLoadWithError - (null)
[22979:c07] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[3]

We are trying this in index.html.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

             function onDeviceReady() {      
              url ="www.myhomepage.com";

            var ref = window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank', 'location=yes');
             //ref.close();  
            }
```

This opens the website with LoadError. if we uncomment the ref.close(); it works fine but we cannot open another url in the below method which is calling when we scan an item.

```
 function updateContent(data) {
                var url = "http://www.mywebpage.com?searchTerm=1234" ;
                url = url.replace('1234',data);
                var ref2 = window.open(encodeURI(url) , '_blank' , 'location=yes');
}
```

our requirement is to call a new URL every time we scan an item in cordova which seems to be not working.

Comment: Did you solve it ? I'm facing the same problem.